# What is meant by "mushroom grandeur" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, metaphors

What is meant by "mushroom grandeur" in this context? Is it  metaphorically means instant, like how mushroom blooms?

> "What do you think of that?'' asked his expressive little eyes, when
> something cruel in "mushroom" grandeur or crude style passed by.
>
> -[Ceylon, the Paradise of Adam By Caroline Corner](https://books.google.lk/books?id=MLtcN116N3sC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), pg 45-

Comment: Perhaps "puffed up" like a mushroom? Grandiloquent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A little more context from your source:

> “What do you think of *that?*” asked his expressive little eyes, when something in “mushroom” grandeur or crude style passed by. Bad form he could not endure, nor vulgar taste.

Compare:

> **6.b.** *attrib*. quasi-*adj*. with the sense: Resembling a mushroom in rapidity of development or growth or in brief duration of existence ; upstart ; ephemeral.
>
> [among citations reaching back to 1599:] **1887** *Westm. Rev.* June 269 Radical millionaires, and mushroom aristocrats.
>
> —[*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed6barch#page/782/mode/2up), s.v. **Mushroom**

Punch despises the tasteless grandeur affected by *nouveaux riches*.

Comment: The dictionary used in this answer is awesome :)

Comment: @UpekhaVandebona It is indeed! It is widely regarded as the most authoritative dictionary of English, and is a joy to browse. Be aware, however, that this citation is from the 1st edition, published between 1884 and 1928; since then it has been continually updated and revised. The most recent "edition" is available only online and only by subscription, which is why I don't cite it; but it is accessible through most academic libraries and, I believe, through most public libraries in the UK.